# Using Ajax to post JSON to php session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying post some JSON to a PHP file that in turn creates a PHP session. I have 2 JSON blocks that I want to add to their corresponding PHP session.

Can someone help in identifying the problem? The sessions do not get populated with the JSON data.

oneoff_json and monthly_json do return JSON values.

## Javascript

```
var oneoffOptions = JSON.stringify(oneoff_json);
var monthlyOptions = JSON.stringify(monthly_json);

    $.ajax({
        url:  "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/includes/set_session.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { oneoffOptions: oneoffOptions, monthlyOptions: monthlyOptions },    
    });
```

## set_session.php

```
$_SESSION['oneoffOptions'] = $_POST['oneoffOptions'];
$_SESSION['monthlyOptions'] = $_POST['monthlyOptions'];
```

Comment: Identify WHAT PROBLEM? I dont see a real question yet

Comment: Keeping you code under `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` sounds a bit on the odd side

Comment: The sessions do not get populated with the JSON data. For some reason, it's not being passed through. "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()" is the Wordpress them url.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to decode the json at the PHP create session. All works now.

```
$_SESSION['oneoffOptions']=json_decode($_POST['oneoffOptions'])
$_SESSION['monthlyOptions']=json_decode($_POST['monthlyOptions'])
```